# 401 UNAUTHORIZED when accessing SP 2013 site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, site, iis7

When i try to access my SP 2013 site with `http://localhost:portno/` i got `401 UNAUTHORIZED` error
Similarly, when i try to access with server name like `http://servername:portno/` i got `401 UNAUTHORIZED` error

But when i try to access with `http://sitename:portno/` i can access my site. why is that ? What should i need to change?
In host file i added: serverIP   sitename

how to fix?

Comment: you are trying to access on server or from pc?

Comment: Now i can access http://servername:portno/ on server but not outside server. Let me know how can i access outside server?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the loopback settings?  [Can't pass authentication to  browse a sharepoint site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/14609/cant-pass-authentication-to-browse-a-sharepoint-site/14611#14611)

Also, is you AAM setup to support those other urls?

Comment: +1 for both those cases, they were the first things that sprang to my mind as well.